# Django update template div with success data from Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, list, view

I have select option and selecting option I run ajax to fetch filtered data from my model. The following are my view:

my template with script and console log also I updated below:

I need help how to update my list in the template with new list fetched by success(books) ajax.
(   $('#stock_list').html([books]) is not updating the list )

### View.py

```
def get_stock_list(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    book_type = request.GET.get('book_type')
    books = list(TextBook.objects.filter(type=book_type).values())
    return JsonResponse({"books": books})
```

### stock_report.html:

```
 {% extends 'wstore_base_generic.html' %}

 {% block content %}
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4">
    <div class="card shadow"  id="stock_report">
        <div class="card-header text-center">                
            <h3 class="display-5">
                Stock Report
            </h3>
             <div class="text-right">


            <h5>
                <select id="book_type" name="book_type" >
                <option  value="" selected="selected">---SELECT---</option>
                   {% regroup books by type as type_list %}
                      {% for type in type_list %}
                            <option value="{{ type.grouper }}">{{ type.grouper }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                 </select> </h5>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body" id="stock_list">
            <table id="customers" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                        <th>Item Description</th>
                        <th>Open Qty</th>
                        <th>Received qty</th>
                        <th>Return Qty</th>
                        <th>Issue Qty</th>
                        <th>Adj Qty</th>
                        <th>Balance Qty</th>
                    </tr>                        
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    {% if books %}

                    {% for book in books %}
                    <tr>

                        <td> <a href="{% url 'select_stock_report' book.id %}">{{ book.code }}</a></td>
                        <td>{{book.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{book.open_qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{book.recived_qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{book.return_qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{book.issue_qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{book.adj_qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{book.bal_qty}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        <tr class="text-center">
                            <td colspan="4">No Transaction have been made yet</td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endif %}
                </tbody>
            </table>                
        </div>            
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="print_stock" 
onclick="printDiv('stock_report')">Print</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
{%  endblock %}
{% block js %}
<script>

 $(document).on('change', '#book_type', function(){
   var that = $(this)
 $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/get_stock_list",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'book_type': $(this).val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
        },
        success: function (books) {
            console.log(books);
            $('#stock_list').html([books]);



        }
    })})
 </script>
 {% endblock %}
```

### I am getting console.log(books)

```
 {books: array(4)}

 {
     "books": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "code": "LKG001",
        "type": "BOOK",
        "name": "LKG BOOK 1",
        "open_qty": "0",
        "recived_qty": "328",
        "return_qty": "0",
        "issue_qty": "111",
        "adj_qty": "4",
        "bal_qty": "213",
        "avgcost": "100.55",
        "price": "100.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "code": "UKG001",
        "type": "BOOK",
        "name": "UKG BOOK 1",
        "open_qty": "0",
        "recived_qty": "17",
        "return_qty": "0",
        "issue_qty": "9",
        "adj_qty": "0",
        "bal_qty": "8",
        "avgcost": "200.00",
        "price": "200.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "code": "UKG002",
        "type": "BOOK",
        "name": "UKG002 BOOKS",
        "open_qty": "0",
        "recived_qty": "0",
        "return_qty": "0",
        "issue_qty": "0",
        "adj_qty": "1",
        "bal_qty": "-1",
        "avgcost": "0.00",
        "price": "200.00"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "code": "001",
        "type": "BOOK",
        "name": "001 TEST",
        "open_qty": "0",
        "recived_qty": "0",
        "return_qty": "0",
        "issue_qty": "0",
        "adj_qty": "0",
        "bal_qty": "0",
        "avgcost": "0.00",
        "price": "0.00"
    }
 ]
 }
```

Comment: Maybe instead of returning a JSON response, return an HTML response such that you can easily replace the relevant part in your DOM with the received HTML from your AJAX call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your data return is json you can use `$.each` loop to iterate through your json array then use `value.keyname` to get value from json and append these values inside tds and finally add this html generated inside your table tbody.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
//suppose this is return from ajax
var books = {
  "books": [{
      "id": 1,
      "code": "LKG001",
      "type": "BOOK",
      "name": "LKG BOOK 1",
      "open_qty": "0",
      "recived_qty": "328",
      "return_qty": "0",
      "issue_qty": "111",
      "adj_qty": "4",
      "bal_qty": "213",
      "avgcost": "100.55",
      "price": "100.00"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "code": "UKG001",
      "type": "BOOK",
      "name": "UKG BOOK 1",
      "open_qty": "0",
      "recived_qty": "17",
      "return_qty": "0",
      "issue_qty": "9",
      "adj_qty": "0",
      "bal_qty": "8",
      "avgcost": "200.00",
      "price": "200.00"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "code": "UKG002",
      "type": "BOOK",
      "name": "UKG002 BOOKS",
      "open_qty": "0",
      "recived_qty": "0",
      "return_qty": "0",
      "issue_qty": "0",
      "adj_qty": "1",
      "bal_qty": "-1",
      "avgcost": "0.00",
      "price": "200.00"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "code": "001",
      "type": "BOOK",
      "name": "001 TEST",
      "open_qty": "0",
      "recived_qty": "0",
      "return_qty": "0",
      "issue_qty": "0",
      "adj_qty": "0",
      "bal_qty": "0",
      "avgcost": "0.00",
      "price": "0.00"
    }
  ]
}


/*$(document).on('change', '#book_type', function(){
   var that = $(this)
 $.ajax(
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: "/get_stock_list",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'book_type': $(this).val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}'
        },
        success: function (books) {
            console.log(books);*/
var html = "";
//loop through json array return
$.each(books.books, function(key, value) {
  //append tr
  html += `<tr> <td> <a href="{% url 'select_stock_report' ${value.id} %}">${ value.code }</a></td><td>${value.name}</td><td>${value.open_qty}</td><td>${value.recived_qty}</td><td>${value.return_qty}</td><td>${value.issue_qty}</td><td>${value.adj_qty}</td><td>${value.bal_qty}</td></tr>`
})

$('#stock_list tbody').html(html); //add datas inside tbody
/* }
    })})*/
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-body" id="stock_list">
  <table id="customers">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item Code</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th>Open Qty</th>
        <th>Received qty</th>
        <th>Return Qty</th>
        <th>Issue Qty</th>
        <th>Adj Qty</th>
        <th>Balance Qty</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <!--data will come here -->

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I made changes like this and it is working:    $.each(books, function(index, item) {
                    $.each(item, function(index1, item1) {
                         html += "<tr> <td> <a href= '{% url 'select_stock_report' 1 %}'>"+item1.id+"</a></td> </tr>"
                    });
                  }) $('#stock_list tbody').html(html)